# apache tika throwing zerobytefileexception on non zero byte file

Tags: apache-tika

```
java -jar tika-app-2.8.0.jar somefile
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="pdf:PDFVersion" content="1.4"/>
<meta name="xmp:CreatorTool" content="Scanner System"/>
<meta name="pdf:hasXFA" content="false"/>
<meta name="access_permission:modify_annotations" content="true"/>
<meta name="access_permission:can_print_degraded" content="true"/>
<meta name="dcterms:created" content="2023-06-07T19:43:16Z"/>
<meta name="dcterms:modified" content="2023-06-07T18:54:49Z"/>
<meta name="dc:format" content="application/pdf; version=1.4"/>
<meta name="xmpMM:DocumentID" content="uuid:dbd46d32-696b-4b6f-abc1-b2cbb0485ede"/>
<meta name="pdf:docinfo:creator_tool" content="Scanner System"/>
<meta name="access_permission:fill_in_form" content="true"/>
<meta name="pdf:docinfo:modified" content="2023-06-07T18:54:49Z"/>
<meta name="pdf:hasCollection" content="false"/>
<meta name="pdf:encrypted" content="false"/>
<meta name="xmp:CreateDate" content="2023-06-07T14:43:16Z"/>
<meta name="Content-Length" content="1752059"/>
<meta name="pdf:hasMarkedContent" content="false"/>
<meta name="Content-Type" content="application/pdf"/>
<meta name="xmp:ModifyDate" content="2023-06-07T14:54:49Z"/>
<meta name="xmp:MetadataDate" content="2023-06-07T14:54:49Z"/>
<meta name="pdf:producer" content="Scanner System Image Conversion"/>
<meta name="access_permission:extract_for_accessibility" content="true"/>
<meta name="access_permission:assemble_document" content="true"/>
<meta name="xmpTPg:NPages" content="5"/>
<meta name="resourceName" content="128f506f-639a-4083-830b-01d3a8501008.data.2023-07-20-18-07-24.154bb614-26e3-cf83-5be2-fd6c7da83ef1"/>
<meta name="pdf:hasXMP" content="true"/>
<meta name="access_permission:extract_content" content="true"/>
<meta name="access_permission:can_print" content="true"/>
<meta name="X-TIKA:Parsed-By" content="org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser"/>
<meta name="X-TIKA:Parsed-By" content="org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser"/>
<meta name="access_permission:can_modify" content="true"/>
<meta name="pdf:docinfo:producer" content="Scanner System Image Conversion"/>
<meta name="pdf:docinfo:created" content="2023-06-07T19:43:16Z"/>
<title/>
</head>
<body><div class="page"><p/>
<div class="page"><p/>
<div class="page"><p/>
<div class="page"><p/>
<div class="page"><p/>
</body></html>Exception in thread "main" org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Unable to extract PDF content
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDF2XHTML.process(PDF2XHTML.java:130)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:212)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:298)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:298)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:199)
    at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI$OutputType.process(TikaCLI.java:1071)
    at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.process(TikaCLI.java:493)
    at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.main(TikaCLI.java:256)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to end a page
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.AbstractPDF2XHTML.endPage(AbstractPDF2XHTML.java:817)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDF2XHTML.endPage(PDF2XHTML.java:154)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:365)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDF2XHTML.processPage(PDF2XHTML.java:137)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.AbstractPDF2XHTML.processPages(AbstractPDF2XHTML.java:1370)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:238)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDF2XHTML.process(PDF2XHTML.java:108)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.tika.exception.ZeroByteFileException: InputStream must have > 0 bytes
    at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:185)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.AbstractPDF2XHTML.doOCROnCurrentPage(AbstractPDF2XHTML.java:559)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.AbstractPDF2XHTML.endPage(AbstractPDF2XHTML.java:806)
    ... 13 more

# ls -alt somefile
-rw------- 1 1000 1000 1752059 Jul 20 18:07 somefile
```

so the file is not zero bytes but tika thinks it is.

I can open the file ( it is a pdf ) without any problems. It has 5 pages. Probably something about the file that tika doesn't like.

The file itself is just a scanned document. But tika is able to parse other such files without any problems.

Comment: What is the output of `id` on your command line?  Only the user id 1000 can access the file.

Comment: uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root). It can't be a file permissions issue. We process millions of file this way.

Comment: From the stacktrace, OCR has been triggered on the page, and, for some reason, the RenderResult is returning a zero-byte inputstream.  If you're able to share the file with me privately, I can take a look: tallison@apache.org